# How to get notified when scrolling is ended in Gallery element

Tags: android

I have Gallery element with full screen image. And user can scroll such images.
Is it possible to add some listener to Gallery and receive actions when image is totally on screen and no more scrolling.
I show "Loading..." icon and then load the image. And it doesn't work good when image is changed during the scroll from "Loadin..." to right image. That's why I want to show real image only after scrolling is ended.

Thanks

Comment: I fixed this problem in this way - when right image is ready but scrolling can add wrong behavior I use "imageLoaderHandler.sendMessageDelayed(message, 1000);" and it solves 99% problems because scrolling ends until message is received.